# How can I improve or add detail to this downvoted question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a question about [looney-tunes-world-of-mayhem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looney-tunes-world-of-mayhem) (I created the tag). It is about this violent but cartoony game related to Looney Tunes.

[This is my question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/383364/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-currency-in-looney-tunes-world-of-mayhem) (Undeleted)

Do I need more details about it? If so, how can I improve it? Should I mention the websites that I included that tried to help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any serious issues with the linked question.  It seems clear and includes some history of what you've looked into already.  It's really no different than the numerous [fastest way questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=fastest+way+is%3Aquestion) that are generally accepted.

As for speculations of why it might get downvoted, there's a few possibilities:

- The post reads a bit like you want to avoid putting in the work.  Many games with microtransactions, paying real money **is** the "get rich quick" option.  I'm not familiar with that particular game, but perhaps wording the question to ask which specific levels/modes offer the most currency per amount of playtime?
- Someone simply has issues with that particular game.  Not a good reason for a downvote, but there's no requirement that reasoning be valid.